# Merge two variables

Tags: php

How can I merge two variables?

My code:

```
$cases = $message->case_number;
$messageText = $message->password;

if (!empty($message->template)) {
    $cases = str_replace('_CASE_', $cases, $message->template->text);
    $messageText = str_replace('_MESSAGE_', $messageText, $message->template->text);
}
```

How can I merge `$cases` and `$messageText`?

*Edit for clarity, from comments below*

I want to replace $messageText with MESSAGE and $cases with CASE in just 1 variable something like

```
$test= str_replace('CASE', $cases, 'MESSAGE',$messageText, $message->template->text);
```

Comment: have you tried resolving this yourself first?

Comment: "_Merge two functions_" or "_How can I merge two variable?_"??

Comment: You could just pass  `$cases` instead of `$message->template->text` into the second `str_replace()` if you just need both replacements done in the same string (or pass an array of both replacements into `str_replace()` instead of one at a time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass both replacement items in to [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) at the same time using an array...

```
if (!empty($message->template)) {
    $output = str_replace(['_CASE_', '_MESSAGE_'], 
                          [$cases, $messageText], 
                          $message->template->text);
}
```

Comment: lol you have two strings not an array. This question is a little weird

Comment: @James, the question isn't worded very well, but the intention can be (IMHO) clarified by the comment on one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dot to concatenate strings, like this:

```
$firstname = 'Dave';
$middlename = 'Brexit';
$lastname = 'Davis';

$fullname = $firstname . ' ' . $middlename . ' ' . $lastname; // 'Dave Brexit Davis'
```

Comment: But I want to replace $messageText with _MESSAGE_ and $cases with _CASE_ in just 1 variable

something like 

    $test= str_replace('_CASE_', $cases, '_MESSAGE_',$messageText, $message->template->text);

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? You said in your question you want to know how to merge two vars together, and the code clearly shows those vars a s strings, hence my answer.

Comment: Code. Input. Expected Output. Actual Output. Any Error messages. THIS is how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always merge two or more variables together by just putting dot between them.

```
$cases = $message->case_number;
$messageText = $message->password;

if (!empty($message->template)) {
    $cases = str_replace('_CASE_', $cases, $message->template->text);
    $messageText = str_replace('_MESSAGE_', $messageText, $message->template->text);
    $merged = $cases.$messageText;
}
```